# How to enable list search with powershell

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

Have a 2013 Farm and I am curious if there is a way to turn on Search This List for a List or Library from PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a setting what you can change. This feature comes with the View of the List or Library.

This option gets displayed on the View when the view Style is set to "Default"

You can read this http://www.sbrickey.com/Tech/Blog/Post/SharePoint_Feature_Request_Deploying_View_Styles to find more about the Styles and how to set it via PowerShell.